# How to prove this inequality $ \|Z u\|^2 \leq 4\left\|Z^2 u\right\|\|u\| $

Tags: inequality, semigroup-of-operators

I don't really have an idea how to attack this problem, and I also wasn't able to find a proof.

> Let $Z$ be the generator of a semigroup of contraction on a Banach space $X$. We define $$
> D(Z^{2})=\{u \in D(Z); \quad Zu \in D(Z)
> $$
>   Show the following Identity:
>   $$
> T(t) u-u=t Z u+\int_0^t (t-s) T(s) Z^2 u \,ds
> $$
>   Show that if $u \in D(Z^2),$ then
>   $$
> \|Z u\|^2 \leq 4\|Z^2 u\|\|u\|
> $$

I don't have a strong background in Operator Semigroups so some of these questions might be quite basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u\in D(Z^2)$.

**1)** For all $x\in D(Z)$ and all $\tau\ge 0$ we have
$$T(\tau)x=x +\int_0^\tau T(s)Zx \,ds.$$
For $x=Zu$, we get
$$T(\tau) Zu=Zu +\int_0^\tau T(s)Z^2u \,ds. \quad (*).$$
Integrating $(*)$ over $(0,t)$ with Fubini theorem yields the result.

**2)** It's just an application of the equality: 
\begin{align*}
t \|Z u\|&=\|T(t) u-u-\int_0^t (t-s) T(s) Z^2 u \,ds\|\\
& \le \|T(t)\| \|u\|+\|u\| +\int_0^t (t-s) \|T(s)\| \|Z^2 u\| \,ds\\
& \le 2\|u\| + \left(\int_0^t (t-s) \,ds \right) \|Z^2 u\|\\
& \le 2 \|u\| + \frac{1}{2}t^2  \|Z^2 u\|.
\end{align*}
So, the polynomial $\frac{1}{2}t^2  \|Z^2 u\| - t \|Z u\| + 2 \|u\|$ is nonnegative. Hence its discriminant is nonpositive. That is,
$$
\|Z u\|^2 \leq 4\|Z^2 u\|\|u\|.
$$